# TextBox on Winform not showing my Data C#

Tags: c#, data-binding, textbox, windows-forms-designer, com-port

I'm creating a Windows form where it should list the COM Ports on my PC. I'm trying to add this data to a ComBox, where it will list/display all my COM Ports and the details of each one. This is the code.

```
    private void cb1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE Caption like '%(COM%'"))
        {
            var portnames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            var ports = searcher.Get().Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().ToList().Select(p => p["Caption"].ToString());

            var portList = portnames.Select(n => n + " - " + ports.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Contains(n))).ToList();

            foreach (string s in portList)
            {
                cb1.Text = s;
            }
        }
    }
```

This code works perfectly in a Console App, it shows exactly what I need. But in the Windows Form, it is not working. I have googled some possible solutions for this, but none of them worked. I am not an expert on that, but I believe this error could be something related with the Data Bindings, I tried to remove the Data Bindings but I couldn't.

cb1.DataSource = null;
or
cb1.Items.Clear();

These were just two of many things that I tried but none worked.

Comment: you need to show your declaration of cb1 for us to help. YOu should probably try sth like cb1.add((new textbox).text = s) if it is an observable collection

Comment: I am guessing that cb1 is a ComboBox hence you need to be adding the items in it. Try cb1.Items.Add(s); Inside the foreach loop

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently not adding any items to the ComboBox. Check out the modified code.

```
private void cb1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE Caption like '%(COM%'"))
    {
        var portnames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        var ports = searcher.Get().Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().ToList().Select(p => p["Caption"].ToString());

        var portList = portnames.Select(n => n + " - " + ports.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Contains(n))).ToList();

        foreach (string s in portList)
        {
            cb1.Items.Add(s); //THIS LINE CHANGED
        }
    }
}
```

You want to add the available COM Ports to the ComboBox so you have to add a new Item for every COM Port. This items can be selected by the user after they are inserted.

**EDIT:**
To run the code when opening your form you should do something like this:

```
public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();

  using(var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE Caption like '%(COM%'")) {
    var portnames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
    var ports = searcher.Get().Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().ToList().Select(p => p ["Caption"]
                                                                                     .ToString());

    var portList = portnames.Select(n => n + " - " + ports.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Contains(n))).ToList();

    foreach (string s in portList) {
      cb1.Items.Add(s);  // THIS LINE CHANGED
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Dominic Wurzer.
But when I run my code, the items are still not showing on the list. Do I need to change something on the properties from my combo box?

Comment: This code shoud work - are you sure that there are any items in "portList"? Edit: I Saw that your Method is called on "SelectedIndexChanged" you should run the code after the combobox is created. Try to put it after "InitializeComponent();" in your constructor.

Comment: Yes, I tested the same piece of code using a console app, and it worked.  My "InitializeComponent();" is on the top of my constructor.

Comment: Try to put the code above directly under InitializeComponent(); This should fix your issue.